# SQL Query to represent employee check-in and check-out

Tags: mysql

I made the table record as

```
id              | int
employee_code   | varchar
status          | enum('check_in','check_out')
created         | datetime
```

With the following sets of data..which is Check-in and Check-out by employee (4 in a day)

```
id  employee_code   status          created

1   EMP0001         check_in        2021-11-22 08:00:00
2   EMP0002         check_in        2021-11-22 08:00:50
3   EMP0001         check_out       2021-11-22 13:00:00
4   EMP0002         check_out       2021-11-22 13:01:00
5   EMP0001         check_in        2021-11-22 13:31:00
6   EMP0002         check_in        2021-11-22 13:33:50
7   EMP0001         check_out       2021-11-22 18:03:00
8   EMP0002         check_out       2021-11-22 18:04:00
```

Normally 1 employee makes 4 punches...

I want to print fetch record as

```
employee_code   check_in_at            check_out_at           total_time

EMP0001         2021-11-22 08:00:00    2021-11-22 18:03:00    10:03:00
EMP0002         2021-11-22 08:00:50    2021-11-22 18:04:00    10:04:00
```

I used the code

```
SELECT 
  A1.badge_id,
  A1.timestamp AS check_in_at,
  A2.timestamp AS check_out_at,
  TIMEDIFF(A2.timestamp, A1.timestamp) AS total_time 
FROM
  attendance AS A1 
  INNER JOIN attendance AS A2 
    ON A1.badge_id = A2.badge_id
    AND DATE(A1.timestamp) = DATE(A2.timestamp) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND A1.timestamp = 'check_in' 
  AND A2.timestamp = 'check_out'
  AND DATE(A1.created) = '2021-11-22'
```

But its not good as expected..  Any Suggestion.... ?? or code for quick fix

Comment: Why do you think, this is not good as expected. When such aggregations are expected, cross joins are inevitable. Please elaborate, in what aspects is this not good as expected

Comment: Your expected results for `total_time` are wrong. For example the time difference of `2021-11-22 13:31:00` and `2021-11-22 18:03:00` should be: `04:32:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  If you're using MySQL 8+, then it is fairly easy to handle using the difference in row numbers method.  For example:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY created) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_code, status ORDER BY created) rn2
    FROM attendance
)

SELECT
    employee_code,
    MIN(created) AS check_in_at,
    MAX(created) AS check_out_at,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(created), MAX(created)) AS total_time
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    employee_code,
    rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
    MIN(created);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Just getting two enties.... its skipping second and third clock_out and clock in...

Comment: EMP001    2021-11-22 08:00:00 2021-11-22 18:03:00   xxxx

Comment: 8 input records are correctly generating 4 output records.  I don't see any problem with my answer.

Comment: Its woking if i give same as Demo Code , but when i use the code mentioned above i am getting only two entries..

Comment: working but when there is more record like more then 8 it doesn't work...?

Comment: Check your sample data, which is where I suspect the problem is.

Comment: Also possible to get difference between last record and first record ..?

Comment: You should avoid changing requirements after several users have given answer.  That being said, you may edit your question and add data for the new output column which you seem to want here.

Comment: I am not changing the requirements, also asking if that something possible or not... :)

Comment: Most likely, it is possible to do what you want.  Edit your question with the new requirement and I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Updated the question to fetch output... out of 4 records, just need result as first check-in and last check-out with its difference.

Comment: Any update on this .?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for each `employee_code` after each row with `status = 'check_in'` there is a row with `status = 'check_out'`, you can get the time of that next row with `LEAD()` window function:

```
SELECT employee_code,
       created check_in_at,
       next_created check_out_at,
       TIMEDIFF(next_created, created) total_time
FROM (
  SELECT *, LEAD(created) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_code ORDER BY created) next_created
  FROM attendance
) t
WHERE status = 'check_in'
ORDER BY check_in_at;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aba2f24c0e9bc56a7994c87d89bae126).

Comment: Any way to get data like how much break they took..?
Like difference between 2nd Clock_in - 1st Clock Out time.. for each employee...?